# Image of the Veronese Embedding

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Is the image of the general Veronese embedding ever contained in a hyperplane of $P^{n}$? I'm guessing no, but I can't prove it.

Comment: Do you know how choosing $n+1$ (generating) sections of an invertible sheaf determines a map to $\mathbb{P}^n$? That will determine how I answer this question.

Comment: I'm only familiar with the definition of a sheaf from reading on Wikipedia. I'm working out of Shafarevich's Basic Algebraic Geometry 1, hence I only know about quasi-projective varieties.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

No.  To prove it, imagine what it would mean for the image to be contained in a hyperplane: this would mean that some non-zero linear combination of the degree $d$ monomials vanished identically, which is to say, that there is some non-zero degree $d$ homogeneous equation which vanishes identically on $\mathbb P^n$.  Hopefully you can convince yourself that this is not possible.